# How do I know if a Form is hovering over a component?

Tags: delphi, forms, components

I need to know if a (moving) form is hovering over a component (maybe something like MouseEnter and MouseLeave without the mouse).

I have this idea of getting the Left, Top, Height, Width of the component and calculating if the (moving) form's position is within the position of the form. (I'm not exactly sure how I can do this)

Any suggestions on implementing my idea? Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: Are you *assuming* that the "show window contents while dragging" option is set?

Comment: @Rob: Sorry I don't know what that is. (I tried googling this but the results are all kinds of "show window.." problems)

Comment: Put quotes around it and search again. Or explore the "display properties" control panel (under "effects").

Comment: Oh I see it now. Yes, I'm assuming "show window contents while dragging" is set. Is that a bad thing?

Comment: Depends on why you think you need other windows to know where the currently dragged form is, I guess. If the setting is turned off, then programs won't get to observe a form being dragged somewhere. The form will be one place, and then it will suddenly be someplace else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var
  P: TPoint;  
  R1, R2, I: TRect;
begin
  P := TheComponent.ClientOrigin;
  R1 := TheComponent.ClientRect;
  Windows.OffsetRect(R1, P.X, P.Y);
  P := TheForm.ClientOrigin;
  R2 := TheForm.ClientRect;
  Windows.OffsetRect(R2, P.X, P.Y);
  if Windows.IntersectRect(I, R1, R2) then
    // the Form is over the component
  else
    // the Form is not over the component
end;
```